# Decode in insert statement

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I have many columns in table of which 2 columns are
A : number
B : varchar

I am trying to insert value in B based on value of A from java.

```
insert into table(A,B) values (? , decode('A',110,'ABC',NA));
```

this gives me an error : `illegal number`

So i tried the below :

```
insert into table(A,B) values (? , decode('A','110','ABC','NA'));
```

This always inserts `NA` in the column.

Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: I think you should not use "?" in place of number

Comment: Remove the quotes around the column name (in your example, A instead of 'A')

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `'A'` you should provide the content of variable `A`